# Google maps API - retrieve latlng from origin of directions?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, latitude-longitude, directions

Im wondering on how to retrieve the latlng from the origin of a directions request when the route has been calculated. 
I want to use this to draw a circle around the origin of the route thats been made.

```
function calcRoute() {
start = document.getElementById("start").value; //value from start textbox
end = document.getElementById("end").value; //value from end textbox

var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};
directionsService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    //if route can be generated
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);

        //circle.setCenter();

    }else{
        //display window alert with status error
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
    }
});
}
```

The textboxes that are used for the origin and destination use the autocomplete method from the google dev page which is inside my initialise function that returns all types of locations.

```
//autocomplete section
var inputStart = document.getElementById('start');
var optionsStart = {}; //Empty which will return all types
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputStart, optionsStart);

var inputEnd = document.getElementById('end');
var optionsEnd = {}; //Empty which will return all types
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputEnd, optionsEnd);
//--------------------------------------------------
```

ive researched about, would I need to just return addresses then use a geocoder to retreive the data I want or can this be done with the way my code is now.

I have seen this piece of code around, but no idea how to implement it if this helps too.

```
 result.routes[0].legs[0].start_location;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would work yes...

`result.routes[0].legs[0].start_location` is a [LatLng object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng).

So you can use that to create a marker or set your circle center point. We miss the code where you create the circle though. But you could do something like that:

```
circle.setCenter(result.routes[0].legs[0].start_location);
```

and if your circle is not yet created:

```
var circleOptions = {
    fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
    fillOpacity: 0.25,
    map: map,
    center: result.routes[0].legs[0].start_location,
    radius: 10000
};

var circle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);
```

Below is a complete example:

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/25o5wk46/)</kbd>

Comment: Ahh thank you, i think i tried declaring the latlng as a variable and inputting the variable into the setCenter parameter but wasnt working.. Thanks! Now I just need to be able to edit the raidius with some sort of slider,, time for more research haha. Thanks again.

Comment: Welcome. But if you do `var xxx = result.routes[0].legs[0].start_location` and use that variable in the `setCenter()` there is no reason that would not work... But you have to use that **inside** the request function.